# how to get value of label for particular dynamically created textbox

Tags: php, jquery

I have an table where one element is my id and other is marks, by fetching data from database there are many rows in the table with many id and textbox. if I try to enter the value into textbox and insert into table the value which is marks always goes to last id . Is there any way to link them?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
  <th>id</th>
    <th>marks</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
echo"<script>   var stu_id={$stu_id};        var sub_id={$sub_id};</script>";
$statusquery="SELECT * from module WHERE module_stu_id={$stu_id} and module_sub_id={$sub_id}";

        $statusofmodule=mysqli_query($connection,$statusquery);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($statusofmodule)>0)
        {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($statusofmodule);

          $status=$row['status_detail'];
          $remainq=$row['remainq'];
          $attempts=$row['attempts'];

      }
<?php
  echo"<td width=auto ><input type='number' id='rq'  name='remainqq' onchange=\"getremainq(this.value,i,sub_id,module_no)\" style=' width: 30px'  ></td>";
  ?>
the stu_id and sub_id i got from tables that code not mentioned here
```

Comment: What You tried show the code

Comment: echo"<td width=auto ><input type='number' id='rq'  name='remainqq' onchange=\"getremainq(this.value,i,sub_id,module_no)\" style=' width: 30px'  ></td>";

Comment: this fetches the last value of id

Comment: Put the code in question @Mahesh

Comment: [edit] link is here.